# OpenCL sending float3 host to device

Tags: opencl

I have a problem to send some data to my device.

The data type I want to receive in my kernel is :

```
typedef struct{uint3 nbCells;
    float3 worldOrigin;
    float3 cellSize;
    float3 gridSize;
    float  radius;
} grid_t;
```

and the data type I send from the host is :

```
typedef struct{
    uint nbCells[3];
    float worldOrigin[3];
    float cellSize[3];
    float gridSize[3];
    float radius; 
} grid_t;
```

but it didn't work well.

I send that:

```
8, 8, 8; 0, 0, 0; 1.03368e-06, 1.03368e-06, 1.03368e-06; 8.2694e-06, 8.2694e-06, 8.2694e-06; 3e-07
```

but in my kernel I receive that :

```
8, 8, 8; 0, 0 1.03368e-06; 1.03368e-06, 8.2694e-06, 8.2694e-06; 3e-07, 8.2694e-06, 0; 1.16428e-05
```

I known the float3 is in reality considered like float4 in Opencl, so I try with float4 and array of 4 float, but it didn't work too. I try to receive the data with array of 3 float instead float3 and it work perfectly. Its seems, in opencl, a structure composed with 3 float haven't got the same memory size that an array of 3 float.
And with the same structure, but with double instead of float, that work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**You should never try to match CL types to non-CL types. Unless you really know they do match.**

If this is your kernel type:

```
typedef struct{
   uint3 nbCells; 
   float3 worldOrigin; 
   float3 cellSize; 
   float3 gridSize; 
   float radius; 
} grid_t;
```

This should be your host types:

```
typedef struct{ 
   cl_uint3 nbCells; 
   cl_float3 worldOrigin; 
   cl_float3 cellSize; 
   cl_float3 gridSize; 
   cl_float radius; 
} grid_t;
```

Thats the use case for the cl data types defined on the host side (when you include the cl.h).

Your error comes from using a float3 type (same as float4), and emulating that type with a `float[3]` instead of `float[4]`.

Comment: ok thinks. I don't known there are cl_float type. So I change this for all my host data.